# How do I remove all newlines and also escape characters from a string in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html, youtube, gdata-api

For a YouTube web-app I'm building in PHP, I have the simple video player, embedded with an `<iframe>`, and then a `<div>` with information about the currently loaded video (description, id, title, etc).

A `<ul>` contains a list of videos which are fetched using the PHP gData API from YouTube, and each `<li>` contains a link which activates JavaScript to change the video player to the correct video and also update the video info on the page.

Here's the issue: `gData` returns a multi-line, non-escaped sequence for the video description, which doesn't work in JavaScript. How should I remove line breaks and replace them with `<br>` (note that they aren't line breaks like `\n`, they are actual line breaks and newlines).

I also have to escape other things that won't work in a JavaScript string, such as the apostrophe character `'`. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Looks like you removed all the newlines from your question too...

Comment: nl2br() see manual for useage

Comment: Is the data from PHP or from JS, or do you print your PHP data as Javascript code that gets executed?

Comment: Provide an example of the returned data that you're dealing with.

Comment: `actual line breaks and newlines` **are** `\n` (and maybe `\r` too).  `won't work in a JavaScript string`?  Apostrophes work just fine inside double quoted strings.

Comment: Sorry about the missing paragraphs, I didn't think about it. I'll correct it next time. @Rocket: You're right, I wasn't thinking. @Dagon: I tried that, it didn't actually remove newlines, just added `<br>`. @mathieu: The data is from PHP, but gets used later in a javascript function. @Alex: I will, as soon as I try something and clean the code a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marc B has given the best answer. Use json_encode: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php Go, upvote his answer.

The following is my original response:

```
<?php
$data = "Hello, 'world'.\nHow are you doing?\n\"Good?\"\n";
$data = str_replace("\n", '<br>', $data);
$data = str_replace('"', '\"', $data);
$data = str_replace("'", "\'", $data);
echo $data;
?>
```

The same stuff using regex:

```
<?php
$data = "Hello, 'world'.\nHow are you doing?\n\"Good?\"\n";
$data = preg_replace("/\n/", '<br>', $data);
$data = preg_replace("/\"|'/", '\"', $data);
echo $data;
?>
```

Having given those examples, you don't really need to escape both single-quotes and double-quotes. In JavaScript, you can use double-quoted strings as well as single-quoted strings. So, use one and escape the other.

You might also want to escape backslash (replace `\` with `\\`) to make sure that some funny YouTube uploader doesn't try to break your PHP script by placing a `foo\'bar` in the video description. Now, that can break your script if you don't escape backslash because the JavaScript string after replacements would now look like: `'foo\\'bar'` which is a syntax error because the string finishes at `'foo\\'`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. It took some work, because my code was unusually messy for this project, but I ended up using your method and it works. `json_encode()` didn't do what I wanted it to, and although I'm sure it could've worked, this is easier for me to understand, so thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Don't bother trying to escape stuff yourself. Just use json_encode, which'll handle all those details for you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var description = <?php echo json_encode($description) ?>;
</script>
```